# C++11 Mersenne Twister produces same value every time

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, random

Before you tag this as duplicate (as I'm aware that this has been asked many times) I have read through dozens of questions / answers on StackOverflow as well as many other 'tutorials' and such.

Despite following all recommendations that I'm aware of, my code produces the same "random" number every single time I run it. It doesn't look to me like I'm doing anything different to what I should be. Why isn't this working?

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

random_device rd;     // used to initialise (seed) engine
mt19937 mt(rd());    // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 4); // guaranteed unbiased
```

Later in code / within a function:

```
for (it : vec_one) {
    int rand_int = dist(mt); // Generate Random Number
    switch (rand_int) 
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "One!" << endl;
    case 2:
        cout << "Two!" << endl;
    case 3:
        cout << "Three!" << endl;
    case 4:
        cout << "Four!" << endl;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

**Answer from comments**
Missing breaks in the switch statement. It really was that simple. Generator working fine. I forgot to include them in my overtired state and feel quite stupid.
**However...**
The number of comments and answers that skip over this issue highlight how easy it is to do. I feel slightly less stupid now...

Comment: Works just fine for me, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61540450cafd9f1b) for a live example, not sure what you're doing. Can you just post a minimal compilable example? BTW, you don't have `break`s in the `case` statements, so you'll fall through the case switches and you'll end up with `One! Two! Three! Four!` as a display.

Comment: Are you sure this is with MSVC and not with MinGW or something? Last I knew, libstdc++ Windows implementations didn't make `random_device` non-deterministic (which is still perfectly legal from a standard viewpoint).

Comment: What is the result of `cout << rd.entropy()` on your system? See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/. If your system does not have an actual non-deterministic random number generator, you would not expect to see a different sequence each time (and `entropy()` will theoretically return 0), and should use the `mt19937` constructor that [takes an actual seed, instead](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mersenne_twister_engine/mersenne_twister_engine/) (see also the example there).

Comment: What version of Visual Studio/VC++ are you using?

Comment: Some online compilers cache runs. If you add a comment or something, it changes. (Leaving in case vsoftco's link is questioned again)

Comment: @chris Oh, got it. Yeah I see it changing now.

Comment: Oh my god. First comment has it. Missing breaks in switch. I feel awful, every other switch statement I've used in my code has them.
That's what I get for working on this project for 14 hours with barely a single "break" (pun intended?). I have, however, learned a lot about how random_device works. Thank you. 
New policy: have a nap and come back to the issue before bothering anyone on StackOverflow.
Hope this still serves as a good Q/A for those who've made the same mistake in sleepy states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch statement is missing breaks...
The code below does the trick.

```
for (it : vec_one) {
    int rand_int = dist(mt); // Generate Random Number
    switch (rand_int) 
    {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "One!" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout<< "Two!" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout<< "Three!" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout<< "Four!" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Way to see through to the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Technically this is valid behavior. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device):

> `std::random_device` may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to the implementation. In this case each `std::random_device` object may generate the same number sequence.

If you prefer a quote from the standard, it's at [rand.device]/2:

> If implementation limitations prevent generating non-deterministic random numbers, the implementation may employ a random number engine.

[`random_device::entropy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy) is supposed to be used for checking this, but unfortunately it's not implemented properly in most libraries, as the linked doc states (and I can confirm it for GCC 6.3, Clang 3.9 and MSVC 2015).